# how do I configure a new Oracle 11g instance to match the configuration of the old Oracle 10g server

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

How can I compare two Oracle database servers which are on two different machines?

We need to ensure that the new server is setup correctly.

For example, one machine is running Oracle 10g on Windows, and the second machine is running Oracle 11g on Linux.

How can I ensure that we have correctly set up all the parameters on the new 11g machine?

Some of the items I need configured are:

1. Temp Tablespace size
2. SGA size
3. any other particular fine tuning that has been applied on the Oracle 10g machine.

Comment: before you think about changing parameters what are the problems you are trying to address? A default install of Oracle does a pretty good job for many uses.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want them to be running with the same parameters in the first place. Very likely that you want to enable the 11g features. Things that you might want to make sure to be at least equal size are the memory footprint, temp tablespaces and undo tablespaces.

In Oracle 11g you might be tempted to use Autmatic Memory Management. There are some issues with it so it might be smarter to configure your shared pool and database buffer according to the 10g database. In the run check if you are not over or undersized.

Best is to hire a dba to help you with the setup, next best is to dive into [Oracle® Database 2 Day DBA 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm) There is a lot to learn from.